# How many numbers less than L have prime factors solely from a given set of prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

I'm finding how many integers under a limit, $L$, only have prime factors from a given set of prime numbers, $P$. The numbers that meet these conditions are called n-smooth numbers. (I've never used sets before so feel free to correct any mistakes I make). Take, for example, $P = \left\{2, 3 \right\}$, and $L = 25$, there are 10 numbers that are 3-smooth: 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24.

I'm trying to find a method/algorithm that easily finds *how many* n-smooth numbers there are for a given $P$ and $L$. Here's my work so far:

To start, a number from $P$ to any power will be n-smooth as long as it's < $L$. Using the same example from above, this would include the powers of two: 2, 4, 8, 16, and the powers of three: 3, 9. By using the floor function and log, I can essentially tell how many powers of a number there are that are less than or equal to L. The total amount of these numbers can be modeled with this expression:

[image]

But this leaves the other numbers 6, 12, 18, and 24 leftover. I don't know how to account for these "leftover" type of numbers. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The usual term if you restrict to small primes is [smooth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).  A number with no prime factor greater than $5$ is called $5-$smooth.  These are shown in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A051037) where it is conjectured that the number below $n$ is about $\frac {\log(n*\sqrt{30})^3}{6*\log(2)*\log(3)*\log(5)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\# \{m \le L | m=2^a 3^b \} = \sum_{a=0}^{\lfloor \frac{\log L}{\log 2}\rfloor} \lfloor \frac{\log L - a\log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor$$

For $L = 25$, it gives :

$$\lfloor \frac{\log L }{\log 3}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{\log L - \log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{\log L - 2\log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{\log L - 3\log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor+ \lfloor \frac{\log L - 4\log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor$$ $$= 
\# \{1,3,9\} +\# \{2,6,18\}+\# \{4,12\}+\# \{8,24\}+\# \{16\} = 11$$

Comment: Can this equation be altered to accommodate for 3 numbers so m=$2^a 3^b 5^c$? or even more? If so, how?

Comment: @Ryan yes of course, with a double sum $\sum_c \sum_a$

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: @Ryan Work on the formula I wrote, you'll find easily how to generalize it.

Comment: I'm not seeing any patterns that would lead me to generalize the formula. I'm just a high school student and this equation is way beyond the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: @Ryan $\# \{m \le L | m=5^c 2^a 3^b \} = \sum_{c=0}^{\lfloor \frac{\log L}{\log 5}\rfloor} \sum_{a=0}^{\lfloor \frac{\log L-c \log 5}{\log 2}\rfloor} \lfloor \frac{\log L -c \log 5- a\log 2}{\log 3}\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

(This is a comment,
but easier to enter as an answer)

In Chapter 5 of "Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work"
by G. H. Hardy,
there is a discussion of
Ramanujan's statement that
the number of numbers
less than $n$
of the form $2^u 3^v$
is
$\dfrac{\log(2n)\log(3n)}{2\log 2 \log 3}$."

If you look up the book on Amazon,
select "Look Inside",
and search for
"lattice-point",
you can read the chapter.

Comment: You missed a $\lfloor \ \ \rfloor$ ?

Comment: If Ramanujan didn't use them, I won't either. Besides, it was obviously an approximation. The chapter derives bounds for the error in that approximation.

Comment: You didn't mention any approximation..

Comment: I quoted Ramanujan, who was notoriously sloppy about this kind of thing. However, he did pretty interesting stuff.

Comment: You don't understand. You can't say "there is the exact result" if it is only an approximation.

Comment: I never said "there is the exact result."

Comment: come on... read it again